# How to retrieve "Runs Completed" count of more than one Logic App

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a bunch of Azure Logic Apps in my architecture and want to figure the cumulative sum of total runs completed in all the Logic Apps in my architecture. So far, I could only configure a single Logic App to the chart but I am wondering if there is a way to get a cumulative count in a single shot.

Any suggestions are much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this requirement, we can use Azure Log Analytics workspace.

1. We need to create a Log Analytics workspace first. Please refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/learn/quick-create-workspace) to create it.
2. Then enable "Log Analytics" when you create the logic app and choose the Log Analytics workspace which we created above.
   [image]
3. After that, we can see the running log(include the cumulative sum of total runs completed) in the Log Analytics workspace. We can see them by go to the Log Analytics workspace and click "Workspace summary".

[image]
[image]

If you have already created many logic apps and do not want to create them again, you can follow the steps below:

1. Also create the "Log Analytics workspace" as the first solution above.
2. Then [install Logic Apps Management solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/monitor-logic-apps-log-analytics#install-logic-apps-management-solution) in it.
3. After that, go to your logic app and [set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/monitor-logic-apps-log-analytics#set-up-azure-monitor-logs) the logs to send to Log Analytics.

By the way, the logs in Log Analytics workspace will be a little bit of a delay, so please wait a moment for the logs.(In my test, I wait for more than 25 mins).

Comment: Hey Hury, thanks for the suggestion. I believe it is also possible to get the count of the Logic Apps which is in different Resource Groups as well.

Comment: @NadeemAhamed Yes, I think so. If the solution works fine, could you please mark my answer as "accepted", thanks~