# Access and search an Azure Logic app history

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I'd like to be able to search my logic app runs with more than just status/date range, e.g. keywords in trigger body or an action output.

I've been looking into https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/workflowruns/list using https://management.azure.com but seem to be limited to the top 250 and would then need to call the get workflow run actions based on each result.

Is there a best practise way to access/search a logic app history (more than the top 250), in order to search it's content within given actions?

Answer (score 1):

For this requirement, I suggest you to export the logs of logic app to "Log Analytics Workspace".

First, you need to [create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/quick-create-workspace) a "Log Analytics Workspace".

Then [enable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/monitor-logic-apps-log-analytics#enable-log-analytics-for-new-logic-apps) log analytics workspace for your logic app. And go to your logic app, [set up](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/monitor-logic-apps-log-analytics#set-up-azure-monitor-logs) Azure Monitor logs.

Run your logic app a few times and wait for a few minutes(at least 20 minutes). Then you can see the logs in your "Log Analytics Workspace".

After that, you can use [api](https://dev.loganalytics.io/documentation/Using-the-API) to query the logs.

Here is another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60050469/how-to-retrieve-runs-completed-count-of-more-than-one-logic-app/60051269#60051269) which I provided answer also use "Log Analytics Workspace" for your reference.

Comment: is it possible to write logs to application insight?